# stop jQuery execute any further code

Tags: javascript, jquery, iife

Probably the most short question. What if I have these code and I want to stop executing any further after specific point inside jQuery document ready. Does return will do the job in any case?

```
$(function(){

return; //stop executing any further.

alert('passed 1');

(function(){
  alert('passed 2');
})();

check();

});

function check(){
 alert('passed 3');
}
```

Comment: You have the code already, why didn't you just try it!

Comment: Well, it did not work in some cases and I thought there might be other ways and methods of doing it like stop, finish etc. Why did not you just reply like @kapa did.

Comment: Well, now it's valid and @kapa still has the best answer with some useful notes. You have provided 0 of help just so you know...

Comment: I never asked fixing it and you should read the question carefully instead of trolling. What I did ask was "if it would work in any case" and @kapa clearly explained when it would work and when not. I am sorry if you do not understand English or have issues with helping others. Good luck to you ))

Comment: This discussion obviously has no end. It´s your right to help or not but as you see someone bothered to help and you spent more time arguing with me in chat then actually do something useful at this thread. I got your point, hope you got mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` will stop the execution of the function in which you are calling it directly.

So yes, it will work in your case, unless you are putting it in the other two functions (`check` or the self-executing one) - in that case it will of course only stop the execution in the function you have put it into.

I must warn you that this is not a very good practice in most cases. Easily leads to code that is not pleasant to read and not easy to follow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention and some explanation like no others did. Thank you.